# Send emails on gmail

Tags: php, email, vb6

I am wondering if there is a way to send a quick email to my leads on gmail. I want to send each message to store them in the sent folder, I know that it can be done by create each compose message but it will give me the hard work to send the emails to each user and I don't like to use BCC because when I receive the emails from the users, I will only see one message in my inbox. I want to receive each email from each user.

Example:
http://oi57.tinypic.com/ztiy5f.jpg

I don't like to receive the email like this:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/4gl11e.jpg

Is there a way to do that through on VB6, PHP, gmail or whatever it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending mail using PHP, for example. It's not as easy as it used to be.

The sending part, is trivial. Most of the time folks use the `mail` command, pass parameters to it, and voila.

However, with today's overachieving spam filtering via ISPs, etc. -- Chances are very good that your email might not ever get received at its intended address.  It might get there, most likely will be sent to spam, and can have several hours of delay.

The best way to send email, as far as I know, is with SMTP email in PHP. [PHP mail vs SMTP](http://www.jvfconsulting.com/blog/190/PHP_Mail_Function_vs_SMTP_Guaranteed_Delivery.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I don't like to use SMTP because the email won't be in the sent folder. Can I use IMAP to send the emails to users so they can receive my email in their inbox without the spam folder?

Comment: Not sure about the IMAP, as I've never used it. I took a look at this IMAP function in the manual page. Perhaps this is what you're trying to do? http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-move.php